# Producing colored output on cqlsh

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh, nosql

I am using Cassandra 3.9 version and I want to produce colored output on cqlsh.  What is the command for that?

Comment: It's unnecessary to quote your question.

Comment: I will take care of it from the very next time..

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways.  You can create a `~/.cassandra/cqlshrc` file with the following section and option:

```
[ui]
color=on
```

You can also start cqlsh using the `-C` or `--color` flags on the command line.

```
$ cqlsh 127.0.0.1 -u user -p password -C
```

Or...

```
$ cqlsh 127.0.0.1 -u user -p password --color
```

Check the [cqlsh](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlsh.html?hl=color) and [cqlshrc](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshUsingCqlshrc.html?hl=color) sections of the documentation for more info.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But when i am starting cqlsh using the above command then it gives WARNING: console codepage must be set to cp65001 to support utf-8 encoding on Windows platforms.
If you experience encoding problems, change your console codepage with 'chcp 65001' before starting cqlsh. even the output is produced in some unreadable language. please guide me through this...

Comment: @bunny To change the codepage for your console (for those of you using Windows), check the solutions on this superuser answer: http://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8